# Git - How to apply a fix to mainline with other pending changes

Tags: git

Consider the following scenario (It's not ideal, but has occurred nonetheless):

1. The latest commit on my local mainline branch is commit "c1"
2. This commit is not yet ready for checkin because of pending CRs and such.
3. Meanwhile, due to a high priority issue, I need to make another change to mainline. I can't checkin commit "c1" though.

What is the recommended procedure for this?

I was thinking I should create a new branch, say, pre-c1-branch from the commit prior to c1 on mainline. Then cherry-pick c1 and apply it to pre-c1-branch and git reset --hard HEAD on mainline to delete c1 commit from mainline branch. Then I can apply the bug fix to mainline branch and check that in. Once that is checked-in I merge that c1 commit onto mainline.

Ideally, I should started with feature development of c1 on a feature branch instead of mainline. But that's not the case now.

Comment: Did you already push the latest commit prior to c1 to remote?

Comment: Yes. All the local commits on mainline that are ahead of remote-HEAD have been squashed into a single commit c1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your plan sounds good to me although you don’t need to cherry pick at all. Let’s assume, your history looks like this:

```
* --- * --- * --- * (origin/master)
                   \
                    ---- * ---- c1 (master)
```

So you have committed new things to your local master branch with `c1` being the last commit. Now, you want to add a commit to the remote’s master. The simplest way would be to just check that commit out and commit something there:

```
git checkout origin/master
# work
git commit
git push origin HEAD:master
```

When checking out a remote branch, Git will however warn you that you are on a “detached HEAD” and commits you make will disappear if you don’t push them. So a more clean solution would be to just create a branch instead:

```
git checkout -b master-fix origin/master
# work
git commit
git push origin master-fix:master
```

This is essentially the same except that you get a separate branch `master-fix` which you will work on.

Of course, this also means that your local master and the remote’s master still diverge. So it might be more desirable to keep `master` refer to the remote’s master, and put your feature work (`c1`) on a separate branch instead. To do that, you can create a new branch that will hold `c1` and then reset `master` to the remote:

```
git branch my-feature # creates a new branch which is a copy of the current one (master)
git reset --hard origin/master # reset the master branch to the remote’s state
# work
git commit
git push origin master
```

This will probably be the cleanest solution. And if you are done with your feature, you can just merge the feature into the master branch using `git merge my-feature`.

Comment: I may have some misconceptions, but I thought the last option wouldn't work because the my-feature branch is created from the local master and once I reset the local master branch the my-feature branch would also loose the change because after all, the new my-feature branch does not have a copy of the commit c1 .. Just a pointer to it ... No?

Comment: There are no copies. Branches are always just pointers to commit objects. So if you create a new branch `my-feature`, it will point at the same `c1` commit that `master` points at. So afterwards, you can make `master` point to some other commit (that’s what `git reset` does) without affecting other branches.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Stash](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing) your current work if you can't commit it now. `git stash`
2. `git checkout HEAD^1` to go to the commit prior to `c1`.
3. `git checkout -b hotfix` to make your important changes on another branch.
4. Commit your changes and deploy them to your customer or whatever.
5. Now you can go back to your previous branch, e.g. master `git checkout master`.
6. `git merge hotfix` to get your hotfix in your dev branch and resolve conflicts, if any.
7. Last thing is to pop your stash, which you did not commit on the beginning with `git stash pop`.

Hope that helps and I didn't miss anything from your description.

Answer (score 0):

You can stash your current change. With command

```
git stash save "message to identify the change"
```

After that you can move to your other branch and commit your other fix.
 To get back the saved change you can use the command

```
git stash list
```

Get the  reflog syntax e.g. stash@{0}

then apply it

like

```
git stash apply stash@{0}
```

Hope it gets clear.

Comment: The commit `c1` already exists, so stashing is not an appropriate solution here.

Comment: The c1 commit already exists. Are you suggesting I uncommit c1 by doing "git reset --mixed HEAD~1" and then stash those changes?